# Conditional Formatting - Not Null

Tags: sharepoint, null, formatting, conditional-statements

I have users that will be adding to the drop down list for a field.
When they add a new criteria, I would like to not have to go back in and format the new choice.

Instead of having to list each choice to get the font to be bold and a color, 
is there a way to say if the field contains content, format the color and bold?